# C# Linq - Refactoring ForEach Loop with Sub List

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Am trying to refactor some data in order to display some charts.

I can't seem to figure out why using the following, it lists all the values at the top rather than being sequential like the source data.

```
var categories = VehicleSales.Select(v => v.name).Distinct().ToList();
        var refactoredResults = new List<StackedColumnChart>();

        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            var subresult = VehicleSales.Where(x => x.vehicleType == category)
                .GroupBy(x => x.vehicleType)
                .Select(gcs => new StackedColumnChart
                {
                    Category = category,
                    Values = gcs.Select(x => (int)x.data).DefaultIfEmpty(0).ToList()
                }).ToList();
            refactoredResults.AddRange(subresult);
        }
```

**Source Data:**

[image]

**Then the actual results and expected results:**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your source data actually sorted by WeekNumber, or is it only sorted that way to show in Excel in your screenshot?  Do you need to add a sorting step in your linq query to ensure such sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without loop and selecting a distinct values, just use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) method and map each group to `StackedColumnChart` using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
var refactoredResults = VehicleSales
    .GroupBy(s => s.Category)
    .Select(g => new StackedColumnChart
    {
        Category = g.Key,
        Values = g.Select(s => s.Value).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

If the original data is not sorted and you'll need to sort the values by week number, you can use `OrderBy` clause before selecting a values `Values = g.OrderBy(s => s.WeekNumber).Select(s => s.Value).ToList()`

Comment: @Harry does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?